# Data Migration Assistant - Cross-database queries

Tags: azure-sql-database, data-migration

I am running an assessment using the Azure SQL Data Migration Assistant (3.4.3948.1). In my initial assessment, I had a function that was calling `fn_varbintohexstr` so I fixed it (read removed the function). I also deleted all our synonyms.

Now I run the assessment more times and it continues to give the 'cross-database queries' error but without listing any more specifics. How can I find out what particular objects it means? Or is it possible that it has somehow cached my result and I need to invalidate it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you have programming objects in that database that reference another database. For example a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Database1.dbo.Table1
```

One of the options you have is to import those external objects to your database and change the three and four-part name references that SQL Azure does not support.

You can also use CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE and CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE on SQL Azure to query tables that belong to other databases that you have to migrate to SQL Azure too.